# With WMI: How can I get the name of the user account who's running my program?

Tags: c#, wmi

I need to restrict access to my application to only one specific user account. I have found classes under WMI to find users accounts, but I don´t know how to recognize which one is running my app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are simpler ways to get the current username than using WMI.

[WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfs49sw0.aspx).[Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.name.aspx) will get you the name of the current Windows user.

[Environment.Username](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx) will get you the name of the currently logged on user.

The difference between these two is that `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` will also include the domain name as well as the username (ie. `MYDOMAIN\adrian` instead of `adrian`). If you need the domain name from `Environment`, you can use [Environment.UserDomainName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userdomainname.aspx).

**EDIT**

If you really want to do it using WMI, you can do this:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
string username = (string) collection.Cast<ManagementBaseObject>().First()["UserName"];
```

Unfortunately, there is no indexer property on `ManagementObjectCollection` so you have to enumerate it to get the first (and only) result.

Comment: Thanks, is much easier and I will use it, but ¿is there a way to do it with WMI?

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to use WMI. Check out [WindowsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx).

```
var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
var username = identity.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is through the Environment class:

```
string user = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
```

There also are several ways to restrict to a certain user (although checking for a role is more common).

Apart from the obvious

```
if (userName == "domain\\john") 
{  }
```

You can also use the following attribute on an entire class or specific methods:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand,  Name = "domain\\john", 
      Authenticated = true)] 
void MyMethod() 
{ 
}
```

Which could be a bit more reliable for low-level, reusable methods.

Note that you could use both, checking for a user with if() as part of the normal flow of the program and the attribute as a safeguard on critical methods.